# Is there a ChromeDriver option to turn off redirect blocking?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chrome driver version 2.40 with chrome V 68.0.3440.106. 
I cant seem to find the chrome driver option to start chrome without redirect blocking. 
 Already tried:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
List<String> switches = new ArrayList<String>();
switches.add("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments(switches);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This came out of the blue this week, and i cant seem to find any reference in the ChromeDriver docs :(
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJkl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I done same incognito using this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: added incognito flag and it still blocks my redirects :(

Comment: :) that work for me. Let me find another solution for the same